# Powershell - removing subfolder recursively in a mapped drive getting error Illegal characters in path

Tags: powershell, mapping, mapped-drive, illegal-characters

I use a mapped drive to copy folder and files into a Sharpoint directory.
Here is my code

```
net use Q: "\\Sharepoint\Dir" /user:domain\user Password

copy-item "C:\Dir" -Destination Q:\

net use Q: /delete
```

Now before copying new files everyday I need to remove 1 subfolder and all his files (data of the day before). Then I try

```
remove-item "Q:\Subfolder" -Recurse -Force
```

but i'm getting this error

```
Illegal characters in path '{0}'. (Parameter 'Q:\Subfolder\.')
```

It's working if i write the whole file path like so

```
remove-item "Q:\Subfolder\file.ext" -Recurse -Force
```

But I need to remove all of the subfolder...

Some of my other unsuccessful tries

```
- remove-item "Q:\Subfolder\*" -Recurse -Force





- remove-item "Q:\\Subfolder" -Recurse -Force







- Get-ChildItem Q: -Directory -Force | ForEach-Object {
               
               $regex = "^te"
               
                       if ($_.BaseName -match $regex) {
                           remove-item $_.BaseName 
                       }
```

Hope someone can help, thanks !

Comment: Assuming your subfolder does not actually called "Subfolder", can you try with `Remove-Item -LiteralPath "Q:\Subfolder" -Recurse -Force` ?

Comment: Thanks but same error... On the other hand -WhatIf parameter always tells me `What if: Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "Q:\Test".`

Comment: Can you provide the exact command you use ? Are you storing the path into a variable that contains double quote (`$mypath='"Q:\Subfolder"'`), if so this path will be invalid.

Comment: Here is my exact command, `net use Q: "\\Sharepoint\Dir" /user:domain\user Password

remove-item "Q:\Subfolder" -Recurse -Force -WhatIf

net use Q: /delete`

Comment: I doubt this is the exact name. This name `D:\Subfolder` works obviouly. I see Sharepoint for the server name, is this an on premise sharepoint ?

Comment: Ok, please remove your comment, user and password name should never been exposed. I am not very familiar with Sharepoint, but I think this is the root of the problem, can you try `Remove-Item -LiteralPath \\content.grp.......\Testpim25\Test -Recurse -Force` to see if you get the error (of course, replace the `......` by the full path ;)

Comment: I thought I edited it.... I tried `Remove-Item -LiteralPath \\content.grp.......\Testpim25\Test -Recurse -Force` same error "illegal character". The fact `Remove-Item -LiteralPath \\content.grp.......\Testpim25\Test\Test.csv -Recurse -Force` is working makes me confuse because it's the same path and I don't get the error

Comment: if the folder is empty, does the command throw the error ? (try without the `-Recurse` parameter), try with ` \ ` at the end of the path too

Comment: Yes the command throw the error even if the folder is empty. Even without the `-Recurse parameter` and ` \ ` at the end of the path